# Wipe a Solaris Disk

Tags: security, solaris, disk

Looking for something similar to [Eraser](http://eraser.heidi.ie/) for Solaris 9-10-11

Anything?

Comment: can you use `dd` with `-if=/dev/random`? I think there is also `scrub` or `shred` available for Solaris, but I cannot tell about safety. Are we talking single files, or whole partitions/disks?

Comment: `yes How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood? > /dev/disk`

Comment: @frostschutz: AFAIK there is some recovery possible if a disk is overwritten by `/dev/null`. Do you happen to know if that is the same if it is a repetitive (i.e. predictable) pattern like you use?

Comment: @Fiximan: it's only possible to recover if it did not get (physically) overwritten. The advantage of random data is that it can not be compressed or optimized away in other means - but it will only make a difference for smart storage media.

Comment: @Fiximan "Overwriting" a disk with `/dev/null` will leave that disk unaffected.

Comment: @jlliagre `/dev/zero` my bad to mix them up.

Answer (score 3):

Solaris has a built in `format` command which has `analyze` and `purge` subcommands to do this. See https://blogs.oracle.com/cmt/entry/erasing_disks_securely for more information.

Comment: We know that but it requires a fair amount of manual intervention at (the worst part) widely separated and unpredictable intervals.  We have several servers and dozens of disks to do.  Something like Eraser would let us create huge batches and then we'd just come back in a week and check on them, which would free up the scarcest resource: sysadmin time & brain cycles.

Comment: Why not just whip up a script that echoes commands into the STDIN stream for `format`?

Comment: I am not sure if that saves any work, given the various configs that will have to be accounted for.